# How can I set up Jenkins CI to use https on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, https, jenkins, continuous-integration

We've recently set up a Jenkins CI server on Windows. Now in order to use Active Directory authentication I'd like to require https (SSL/TLS) for access. Given this setup, what is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Are you running Jenkins under a servlet container such as Tomcat?

Comment: No, just as a Windows service (which I guess is still using Winstone as the servlet container?).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to your %JENKINS_HOME% and modify the jenkins.xml. Where you see `--httpPort=8080` change it to `--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080` you can make the ports anything you want of course, but in my testing (a while ago, it may have changed) if you don't keep `--httpPort=<something>` then Jenkins will always use 8080. So if you simply change `--httpPort=8080` to `--httpsPort=8080`, port 8080 will still use http.

Also, if you want to use your own certificate, there are some instructions at the bottom of this page.

http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

Comment: Thanks George, I've gone through all the steps on the page you linked to. At this point I've got a winstone.ks keystore in my Jenkins folder (and can verify its contents using the java keytool). However, when I restart Jenkins, I get this: `[Winstone 2011/03/16 15:44:21] - Error during HTTPS listener init or shutdown java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` followed by the rest of the stack trace. I'm sure the keystore password is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to close off this topic, the problem I'd run into was that the keystore password and the certificate password (entered when generating the CSR) were different. Once I recreated the keystore with a password that matched the certificate password, the problem was solved.

Comment: Note for those looking to do the same on a CentOS machine, the suggested changes can be made to the file found in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Comment: One other thing is that I needed to set --httpPort=-1 or it wouldn't work.

Comment: After modifying jenkins.xml it needs to restart jenkins server

Comment: You'd definitely want to also generate a self-signed certificate in JKS format as described in [that other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9610431/1127485), and use it by adding `--httpsKeyStore=path/to/keystore --httpsKeyStorePassword=keystorePassword` to "jenkins.xml" as described in the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins). Otherwise Jenkins seems to generate a new certificate each time it restarts, triggering the "Untrusted connection" dialog in Firefox each time as the fingerprints vary.

Comment: I created a self signed cert per the instructions and it worked perfectly. The only hiccup was that I had to reference the address by IP instead of localhost and immediately I could access Jenkins.

Answer (score 21):

Run:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore Jenkins.jks -alias [Name of website] -keysize 2048
```

Answer the questions remembering that `First and last name` is the website URL and should be lowercase. Example:

```
build.jenkins-ci.org
```

`State or province` cannot be abbreviated.

Run:

```
keytool -certreq -Keystore jenkins.jks -alias [Name of website] -file jenkins.csr -keysize 2048
```

Send `Jenkins.csr` to your cert provider and request a PKCS#7 cert which has a `.p7b` extension and starts with:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----
```

Note: Trial certs are not normally available in `.p7b` format but you may be able to combine the `.cer` files using this tool which reported success but didn't work for me. (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html)

Run:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file jenkins.p7b -keystore jenkins.jks -alias [Name of website]
```

Change the `arguments` node in Jenkins.xml to the following prespectivly.

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443 --httpsKeyStore="%BASE%\Cert\Jenkins.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=[Cert password from step 1]</arguments>
```

Troubleshooting:

- If Jenkins doesn't start read the last lines from `Jenkins.err.log`.
- If Jenkins didn't start because of an issue with `Jenkins.xml`, replace the `–` (weird Windows hyphen) characters with an actual `-` (ASCII hyphen).
- If Jenkins starts but the cert still reads as bad, make sure the `[Name of website]` is the actual URL without the `https:` example: `https://build.jenkins-ci.org` would be `build.jenkins-ci.org`.
- If that isn't the issue inspect the `.jks` file using `KeyStore Explorer`. The "Certificate Hierarchy" should show that each cert is nested in another; This is to illustrate the cert chain. If it shows the certs next to each other then it's not correct.
- If it won't start on a specific port, 443 for example, then verify IIS or another app isn't currently using the port.
- If you can see the site on the PC it's hosted on, but not another PC, then verify you aren't getting blocked by a firewall.

Comment: I just wanted to comment that this set of instructions worked flawlessly for me when I needed to set up a new Jenkins build server from scratch.

Comment: Hi I know this is old but is there any way to convert a .crt file into jks?

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Create both public and private Certificate on your jenkin name (convert them into keysore file if its not)
Step2: Import the public certificate into your browser certificate mananger (import into all tabs)
Step3: Host your jenkin using JKS file which contain both public and private key.

For steps refer "[Enable HTTPS in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126736/enable-https-in-jenkins/55515308#55515308)"