# Enable HTTPS in jenkins?

Tags: http, jenkins, https

I have a private network with a local IP.
I want to Enable HTTPS for my Jenkins server which is static IP W.X.Y.Z:8080.

```
Jenkins version 2.9
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have tried configuring in /etc/defaults/jenkins file the following arguments

```
HTTP_PORT=-1
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war -DsessionTimeout=1 --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT  --httpsPort=8081"
```

But I get the following errors. Please help

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Oct 19, 2016 2:18:48 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Logging initialized @811ms
Oct 19, 2016 2:18:48 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Oct 19, 2016 2:18:48 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Using one-time self-signed certificate
Oct 19, 2016 2:18:48 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Oct 19, 2016 2:18:48 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener
winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:149)
at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)`enter code here`
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
```

I found similar issues resolved here but it didn't work for me

EDIT1:
The following changes have been tried in /etc/defaults/jenkins file and restarted jenkins but it didn't work for me.

```
HTTP_PORT=-1
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war -DsessionTimeout=1 --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT   --httpsPort=8443 --httpsCertificate=cert.pem --httpsPrivateKey=key.pem
```

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34463

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25333

Answer (score 23):

You can enable Jenkins via HTTPS with following steps:

1. **Create Certificate using Java**

   ```
    keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias "localhost" -keystore "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\localhost.jks" -validity 365 -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=localhost, OU=OU_name, O=OU_name, L=city, ST=State_name, C=two_letter_country_code" -ext SAN=dns:localhost,ip:ip_address -storepass changeit
   ```
2. **Export `p12` Public Certificate from key-store file**

   ```
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\localhost.jks" -storepass changeit -destkeystore "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\localhost.p12" -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass changeit
   ```
3. **Host Jenkins using key-store (JKS) file**

   ```
    java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=8082 --httpPort=-1 --httpsKeyStore="C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\localhost.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=changeit
   ```
4. **Import the Certificate into Browser**

You may have a question like why we have exported `*.p12` certificate...well, this certificate we are going to import into our browser from where we access Jenkins. The same p12 certificate can be shared between multiple users.

For example in Chrome go to Setting>Search - "Manage Certificate" and click on "Manage Certificate" you will get an "**Certificate**" window. Import the certificate into each tab (Personnel, Other People, Intermediate Certificate Authorities, Trusted Root Certification Authorities, Trusted Publishers, and Untrusted Publishers).

Comment: I tried your steps as is, but getting "Not secure" when I tried to open the site in chrome.On the same machine itself also

Comment: Should I substitute CN for my actual fully qualified name - localhost trusts localhost surely, which would not make sense from another machine on my lan? Or is the CN not relevant?

Comment: I followed this procedure and it worked for enabling ssl on the web portal but now all of my github connections are getting ssl handshake errors.

Comment: I tried it, but even in war file and in service file it throws the same exception like **PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid certificate and you do not want to enable HTTPS for your Jenkins but still want an SSL enable traffic then here is another way.

In my case, I put Jenkins behind my Nginx web server. 
So here are the steps which I follow:

1. I have installed Nginx server. (`sudo apt install nginx`)
2. Copy the cert files in that machine. (Files are: `<my-cert>.crt` and
   `<my-cert>.key`)
3. Changed the nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file to something like this:

   ```
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/<my-cert>.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/<my-cert>.key;
   ```
4. Follow the steps mentioned in the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx).
5. And everything works like a charm...

---

By doing these steps the request flow will be like this:

1. Request goes to Nginx web server.
2. The reverse proxy redirects the traffic to the localhost:8080 (or custom `IP: port`) where Jenkins is running.
3. Jenkins will serve the request and give the response to Nginx
4. Nginx will return the response.

You can do the same with Apache, HAProxy, and squid, see

- [Running Jenkins with native SSL / HTTPS](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=135468777)
- [Running Jenkins behind Nginx](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx)
- [Jenkins behind an NGinX reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy))

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to pass a parameter for the keystore or .pem file of the private key

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

Comment: I tried the above mentioned page but I am stuck at step 4.
Do I need to take certificate from my organisation?

Comment: If your company uses its own internal CA, then you'll need to use it to sign your cert, if not, you'll need to pay a CA to sign it for you. Let's encrypt gives free certs, but you might have to fiddle with the format

Answer (score 0):

If you have your new instance of Jenkins which is a copy of your old Jenkins instance. 
Copy the `cacerts` which will be located at `..\Jenkins\jre\lib\security` to the `jre\secrets` folder of your existing new Jenkins instance.

In `jenkins.xml` change the arguments accordingly, e.g.:

```
<arguments>
    -Xrs 
    -Xmx256m 
    -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
    -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" 
    --httpPort=-1 
    --httpsPort=8443 
    --httpsKeyStore="%BASE%\secrets\keystore" 
    --httpsKeyStorePassword=your.password.here
</arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've researched a lot of finally found a solution that works for me using the following setup.

### 1. Setup

Here's my setup, it's a linux virtual machine on aws ec2. I bought a domain on http://namecheap.com and also its SSL certificates there.
On AWS I've configured the security groups to allow incoming connections to both ports 8443 and also 443 via load balancer and target groups too.

### 2. Create a .jks file

Using the SSL certificates private.key, certificate.crt and certificate.ca-bundle that I got from setup 1. On my jenkins home folder= `/var/lib/jenkins/`, I've created this `.ssl` folder and moved the 3 certificates there, and then created first a .p12 file and then .jks file on the terminal like this (replace PASSWORD by your actual password):

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/.ssl

openssl pkcs12 -export -out jenkins.p12 \
-passout 'pass:PASSWORD' -inkey private.key \
-in certificate.crt -certfile certificate.ca-bundle -name namecheap.online

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jenkins.p12 \
-srcstorepass 'PASSWORD' -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
-srcalias namecheap.online -deststoretype JKS \
-destkeystore jenkins.jks -deststorepass 'PASSWORD' \
-destalias namecheap.online
```

### 3. Make changes to jenkins config files

Have a look at the current status of jenkins

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

You will see something like

```
jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 16:07:30 UTC; 3s ago
 Main PID: 331 (java)
    Tasks: 54
   Memory: 593.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─331 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

That means it's still running on the default HTTP port 8080. In order to change that, edit that file from the second line:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
```

We want to uncomment a few lines and overall change the parameters. Note that JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE is the path to the .jks file that you've created and JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD is its password.

- Environment="JENKINS_PORT=-1"
- Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0"
- Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT=8443"
- Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE=/etc/jenkins/jenkins.jks"
- Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=PASSWORD"

After you edit it, the file should look like this:

```
# Port to listen on for HTTP requests. Set to -1 to disable.
# To be able to listen on privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024),
# add the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability to the AmbientCapabilities
# directive below.
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=-1"

# IP address to listen on for HTTPS requests. Default is disabled.
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0"

# Port to listen on for HTTPS requests. Default is disabled.
# To be able to listen on privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024),
# add the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability to the AmbientCapabilities
# directive below.
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT=8443"

# Path to the keystore in JKS format (as created by the JDK's keytool).
# Default is disabled.
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE=/etc/jenkins/jenkins.jks"

# Password to access the keystore defined in JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE.
# Default is disabled.
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

Notice also this file on lines 3 and 4 from image 35: `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf`, have a look at it too:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
```

In case it's empty just write this line of code on it, save and quit:

```
[Service] Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8443"
```

Great, now you should restart jenkins and reload daemon with sudo. Then have a look again at jenkins' status with `sudo systemctl status jenkins`

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl status jenkins -l
```

Now this is the new output that you should be seeing. Jenkins is running on HTTPS via port 8443, try now https://<YOUR_IP>:8443

```
    jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 16:10:08 UTC; 58min ago
 Main PID: 4614 (java)
    Tasks: 57
   Memory: 2.3G
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─4614 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --httpsKeyStore=/etc/jenkins/jenkins.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=PASSWORD
```

I hope this works for you too.

Answer (score -1):

this thread shows as the top hit, but lack actual information.
if you run jenkins on linux vs windows
use openssl create self-signed certs
if you have certs convert them to pkcs12
whether self-signed or issued you have to import them in to java keystore
keystore steps here
1.https://sopblog.com/how-to-enable-ssl-in-jenkins-server/
and HTTPS section here
2.https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The first link is dead.