# Setting up HTTPS for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

What is the recommended method for setting up HTTPS for Jenkins?

1. Setting up HTTPS in Jenkins itself?
2. Using Apache as proxy for HTTPS setup?

We have a VM in which Jenkins is the only application.

Comment: What's the OS distribution of your VM?

Comment: Refer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126736/enable-https-in-jenkins/55515308#55515308"

Answer (score 2):

Method I use and I believe to be the most simple is to use nginx as proxy, example configuration:

```
root@redacted-jenkins-2:/etc/nginx/sites-available# cat jenkins_http.conf
#Ansible managed

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name jenkins.redacted.com.ar;
   return 301 https://jenkins.redacted.com.ar$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name jenkins.redacted.com.ar;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.redacted.com.ar/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.redacted.com.ar/privkey.pem;
   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.redacted.com.ar/fullchain.pem;
   include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
   location / {
     proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_redirect http:// https://;
     proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }

}
```